# Simulate delay in django's view by sleep

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

In my django app, users are able to define some delays (in seconds) on particular actions - its being used to simulate network delays.

It is possible that I will end up with hundreds of such events.

What I've implemented so far, in my django's view, I simply do:

```
class NetworkDelayView(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = Event.objects.get(short_uuid=kwargs.get('uuid'))
        if obj.enable_delay:
             sleep(obj.delay)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am not sure if its a best way to do this from a few reasons:

- threads - as far as I understand, it will block all requests
- I run my django/python apps on production on shared hosting, using passenger

Any suggestions if its a proper way of doing this? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: It sounds like you need to simulate delay; but not have the thread be blocked on the delay. From a cursory read; it looks like passenger does not support this workflow. Have you looked into the async mode of uWSGI http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Async.html

Answer (score 1):

Above approach is not good at all, You should schedule the task and perform all action in that task. Task will run after the delay and you will not be blocked for further requests. Use celery for the async task.

https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/

Use coundown for delaying the task for some time.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown

Comment: How would you delay a HttpResponse using celery?

Comment: No, httpResponse cannot be delayed via celery and it is also not a good to delay http response.

Comment: As I said, its being used to simulate network delays, so it must be delayed - its a matter of how, not if ;)

Comment: @dease If it's a matter of how then I think sleep would be good here.